# Filtrar JSON do Feed da Graph Api do Facebook

Tags: json, facebook

O *JSON* que a *Graph API* retorna do *Feed* de uma página usando o endereço "graph.facebook.com/*ID*/feed?access_token=_ACCESS_TOKEN_" exibe o *Feed* completo, mas eu queria apenas as postagens feita pela própria página. Como faço pra filtrar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Com `/{page-id}/posts` mostrará apenas os posts que foram publicados pela página.

Para mais detalhes veja a documentação deste item [aqui](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/page/feed/).

Comment: Resolveu o problema, mas indo mais a fundo... existe a liberdade de filtrar esses posts via URL? Exp.: {URL}?filter=xxx

Comment: Não sei, teria que pesquisar nos docs. Vocẽ já deu uma olhada neles?

Comment: Já, mas como é inglês eu apanho um pouco. Valeu!

Comment: Tenta ai: {URL}?q=value